# Alternative for PHP mail

Tags: php, http

In relation to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927430/sometimes-big-delay-when-using-php-mail/2931752#2931752) I'm looking for an alternative way to send an order from my website to the division in my company that processes the order.

Currently I use PHP mail(), but frequently this gives problems. Big delays occur. Are there alternatives to PHP mail() that *pushes* the order to my company? So I prefer not to poll the website.

Comment: Do you know why there are delays? SMTP/Sendmail configuration? DNS routing? etc.

Answer (score 5):

`mail()` is fine for simple stuff, but often you want a more robust library that has solved the mail problem in PHP.

My personal choice is [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Also from reading your other question, could this be of benefit

- Your app writes the order email to database, in a queue.
- You have a Cron running, that sends say 30 emails every 10 minutes.
- It then removes the last sent 30, ready to be processed again in 10 minutes.

The advantage is that when you have a queue of emails to be sent out, they can be processed in batches, and also you will have a copy in the database if the mail fails. It will be easier to query the database then chase up the mailed that was undelivered (or delivered late).

Comment: He said in his previous question that he is averse to storing the order in a database.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I use PHP mail(), but frequently this gives problems.

I'll bet you a lot of money it does NOT frequently give problems.

I have **never** come across problems in PHP's mail function. I have seen problems with bad php.ini settings for mail, and a host of problems with the programs which process mail **after** it has left PHP. Your use of the word "frequently" implies that it works some of the time, so, in the absence of frequent updates to php.ini, the problems are all on your mail handling infrastructure.

Indeed - I would recommend you go have a look at the PHP bug list - there will be lots of reports about problems getting mail from scripts to users inboxes - but **none** of them will be due to a failure of the PHP code.

So if the problem is elsewhere, using a replacement SMTP client will have **no effect whatsoever** (unless you configure it to bypass the bad MTA).

Understanding how email works, and why it fails, is far from trivial. When you add in to the mix, the lengths some people go to (usually undocumented) to prevent spam, it starts to become very complicated. Even if you had given precise details of your infrastructure and configuration, it would be difficult to even hazard a guess as to where why and how it is failing.

Certainly, you need to start by looking at your email logs and headers and checking your MTA and MUA configurations to start to resolve the problem.

C.

Comment: You are right I am having issue setting up mail in my Server to actually send it out. Any recommendation?

Comment: You appear to be using sendmail currently - it's an excellent tool and normally very reliable - however it does take a lot of skill to configure and manage. Since it is very reliable and gives very high throughput when it is configured, and is working at least some of the time I wouldn't suggest switching it for something else straight away. Start by harvesting the headers from emails that have been sent and monitoring the size of your mailq to identify where the bottleneck is occurring - there seems to be *multiple* hops between your webserver and the recipient.

Comment: I ended up using PHP Mailer. Needed very minimal configuration!

Comment: i think what OP means is exactly that the mail function frequently gives problems by being a shitty function that gives you no clue what happened, if there eventually is a problem etc. I wonder why that is so hard to understand.

Comment: @Toskan: the internet email system (of which SMTP is only a small part) is designed to operate asynchronously and therefore cannot report the outcome when the mail is sent. That's what logs and DSNs are for.

Comment: On a trivial inspection it appears the op did not configure his MTA to process its queues regularly, that shorting it out resolved the problem proves it. Perhaps he (or she) will be back to ask more questions when he runs into the performance, availability and capacity issues caused by creating the SMTP connection from within a PHP handler.

Answer (score -1):

There is inherent insecurity in using SMTP to transmit orders. Not to mention the delays caused by all the routing, spam-checking, etc. that is caused by using the mail server. Are you sure you need to email the order? Wouldn't something more along the lines of a server-to-server HTTP transfer, perhaps XML-based, be a better option?

You could use a second server in the processing division that would receive the order from your web server via a protected (firewalled) connection that would process the order, in this case making it available to the person in the order processing division who reads and deals with the order.