# PHP : Alternatives for Mail.php

Tags: php, pear, mailer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative for PHP mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949891/alternative-for-php-mail)

Hi My hosting provider does not allow me to install anything using pear , so is there any other alternative to get the functionality of php pear.

I need a fully tested easy to use mailer .Any help

Comment: [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) is pretty well-liked around here.  (this question is likely to be closed as not-constructive, though)

Comment: Googling around it seems http://swiftmailer.org/ is the most popular alternative, have you looked into that?

Comment: you can do whatever you want with `mail()`, but it's painful and unreliable.

Comment: Odd that PHPMailer still refers to PHP 6 on its website though...

Comment: You don't actually have to install Pear modules the way the documentation says. Most often, it's enough to just copy the code files into your web root. The only problem you may have is including the class files, as the documentation will expect the class to be available within your PATH variable, so you'll need to adjust the actual path you're including it from.

Comment: @Ashley Sheridan Do i have to copy paste all the contents from Mail folder and Mail.php into the include folder ? After doing this do i need to include those in Mail.php ?

Comment: The PEAR documentation has detailed instructions on how to use the  PEAR Remote Installer: http://pear.php.net/manual/de/installation.shared.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). It is very powerful lib.

Comment: If only your provider allows you to use php7

Answer (score 2):

Make your life easier and go with [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) or [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). I personally prefer PHPMailer.